# How to replace value on named capture

Tags: powershell

Source txt file:

```
,,leia,Arrears,TESTaffil,,User,,,,,,286619,,,
,,anakin,Arrears,TESTstud,,User,,,,,,304119,,,
,,r2d2,Arrears,TESTstud,,User,,,,,,999333,,,
,,deathstar,Arrears,TESTaffil,,User,,,,,,999111,,,
```

Output

```
,,leia,Arrears,TESTaffil,,User,,,,,,286619,,,
,,anakin,Arrears,TESTstud,,User,250,,,,,304119,,,
,,r2d2,Arrears,TESTstud,,User,250,,,,,999333,,,
,,deathstar,Arrears,TESTaffil,,User,,,,,,999111,,,
```

i tried using csv get-content but the text have no header, how about select-string?

Comment: use `Import-Csv` and the `-Header` parameter to load it into PoSh. you can just give it a list of numbers if you have no column header names.

Comment: Whatever you are asking is unclear. What are you capturing? What should be replaced?

Comment: sorry being unclear, what im tying to achieve is to add or replace the value next to Users and only add value to line having string Teststud

Answer (score 0):

It seems your file has 16 fields, but no headers.
You can still use Import-Csv on this if you provide these headers. Then, using the columnames you can specify all fields individually.

Something like

```
# create an array of headers, In this example, I'm just using 'Col_1' .. 'Col_16'
# It would of course be better to name the fields for what they contain, but only you would know that..
$headers = 1..16 | ForEach-Object { "Col_$_" }

# Now import the file so we get an array of **objects**. Each object will have 16 properties.

$data = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\SomeFolder\TheFile.csv' -Header $headers
# loop through the rows of the data and update when needed
foreach ($item in $data) {
    # only change data if the field at 'Col_5' contains 'TESTstud'
    if ($item.Col_5 -eq 'TESTstud') {
        # update the field next to Col_7 (the field containing 'User')
        $item.Col_8 = 'SomeReplacementValue'
    }
}

# Save this updated data as (new) proper CSV file
$data | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\SomeFolder\TheUpdatedFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```